# how to remove test mode in windows

Tags: windows

What is test mode and how to remove test mode watermark in windows 7 ?

When Windows Start The following message was displayed in desktop

***Test mode Windows 7 build 7600***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7, like Windows Vista has several watermarks which appear when certain situations warrant it so. One of them is the Test Mode watermark. This watermark may appear in the bottom right part of your Windows desktop, if you install an application whose drivers are not digitally signed by Microsoft and if they are still in the testing phase. What is Test Mode in Windows

Most are familiar with For testing purposes only, Evaluation copy, Safe Mode, etc watermarks. The Test Mode is not so familiar a watermark, however!

The TESTSIGNING boot configuration option determines whether Windows 7 or Vista will load any type of test-signed kernel-mode code. This option is not set by default, which means test-signed kernel-mode drivers will not load by default on 64-bit versions of Windows Vista and later versions of Windows.

For 64-bit versions of Windows 7 & Vista the kernel-mode code signing policy requires that all kernel-mode code have a digital signature. However, in most cases, an unsigned driver can be installed and loaded on 32-bit versions of Windows Vista and later versions of Windows, explains MSDN.

When you start your Windows 8-based or Windows 7-based computer, you receive the following message in the lower-right corner of the desktop, depending on your version of Windows.

Windows 8.1

Test mode Windows 8.1 build 9490

Windows 8

Test mode Windows 8 build 9200

Windows 7

Test mode Windows 7 build 7600

Note This message may also mention a more specific edition of Windows. For example, the message may be, “Test mode Windows 8 Pro build 9200.”

Windows 8 To fix this problem manually in Windows 8, follow these steps:

Swipe in from the right, click or tap Search, and then type cmd. Alternatively, type cmd on the Start screen. Tap-and-hold or right-click Command Prompt in the search results. Select Run as administrator on the menu that appears at the bottom of the screen.

Note If you are prompted by a User Account Control window, tap or click Yes. In the Command Prompt window, type the following command, and then press Enter:

```
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING OFF
```

After you see the confirmation, close the Command Prompt window. Save any unsaved work, and then restart the computer.

Windows 7 To fix this problem manually in Windows 7, try these methods, in the given order.

Method 1

Click Start, and then type cmd in the Search box. Under Programs, right-click cmd.exe, and then click Run as administrator. At the command prompt, type the following text, and then press Enter:

```
bcdedit /set TESTSIGNING OFF
```

Close the Command Prompt window, and then restart your computer.

Note If this method does not resolve the issue, go to Method 2.

Method 2

Click Start, and then type cmd in the Search box. Under Programs, right-click cmd.exe, and then click Run as administrator. At the command prompt, type the following commands, and press Enter after each command:

```
bcdedit.exe -set loadoptions ENABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKSbcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING OFF
```

Close the Command Prompt window, and then restart your computer.